# "Sorry, something went wrong." message when sharing on facebook using share dialog

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, facebook-share

I am using django to share a page on facebook. I use the below code to url

```
var link = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1234567890&display=popup&name=' + name + '&description=' + description + '&picture=' + picture + '&link=' + caption + '&caption=' + caption + '&redirect_uri=' + redurl;
window.open(link, "Share", windowFeatures);
```

The url that finally gets formed is as below

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1234567890&display=popup&name=GameStore:%20come%20and%20play!&description=Hey%20!!!%20I%20am%20playing%20to%20Breakout&picture=https://res.cloudinary.com/dma8tn6ge/image/upload/c_fill,h_75,w_75/profile-picture.png&link=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/game/player/1/&caption=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/game/player/1/&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/fb_redirect
```

This is triggered from a button click event in javascript. But when I click it the window opens with the message :

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>   We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

p.s. I obviously use the correct app id in my code and not 1234567890.

Could somebody guide me what am I dong wrong

Comment: Facebook will never be able to access localhost

Comment: thanks, it worked on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

It started working when I pushed it to Heroku. I guess as Sayse mentioned, it will not be able to access localhost.